# Calculate data in real time - Grid (using Vaadin 7.4.9)

Tags: grid, vaadin

Here Is my code, and I need your help. I need add listener to my grid, which can add result in real time to the grid (no after e.g. click on the button). I want add the number to the column "firstNumber", second number to the column "secondNumber" and then in the column "result" will be the sum of numbers.

firstNumber: "1" , "secondNumber": "1" and result will be "2".

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
IndexedContainer container = new IndexedContainer();
grid.setContainerDataSource(container);
container.addContainerProperty("firstNumber", Integer.class, 0);
container.addContainerProperty("secondNumber", Integer.class, 0);
container.addContainerProperty("result", Integer.class, 0);


/* --- Need add this to the listener or method --- */

Item item = container.getItem(0);
int firstNumber = item.getItemProperty("firstNumber").getValue();

item = container.getItem(0);
int secondNumber = item.getItemProperty("secondNumber").getValue();

result = firstNumber + secondNumber;

item = container.getItem(0);
item.getItemProperty("result").setValue(result);

/* -------------------------------- */
```

Comment: You may look at this [valueChangeListener](https://vaadin.com/api/7.7.0/com/vaadin/data/util/IndexedContainer.html#addValueChangeListener-com.vaadin.data.Property.ValueChangeListener-) that will tell you when a value inside your container changes, or this [itemSetChangeListener](https://vaadin.com/api/7.7.0/com/vaadin/data/util/AbstractInMemoryContainer.html#addItemSetChangeListener-com.vaadin.data.Container.ItemSetChangeListener-) that will told you when the whole itemSet changes.

Comment: Where do you get `firstNumer` and `secondNumber` values?
Does the user edit the grid? They come from somewhere else? If they are added at the start with the container, you don't need a `Listener`. Can you provide us a little more info?

Comment: @Shirkam Data are from "editor" no from file ... Input from keyboard

Comment: Then `ValueChangeListener` should do the trick. I will post an answer when I can.

Comment: @Shirkam can you write your code (idea) here ? I read documentation, but i need the code, or code example ... no only text :D And then, when it will be good, you can post an answer and I mark the answer as right :)

Comment: Ok, basically, I was to told you that you must loop through your entire `Container` to recalculate things. The `ValueChange` event doesn't tell you much info, only which property has been modified and the new value. This approach is ok as you only have to sum 2 numbers (*I doubt you have millions entries in your container*). I wont write that code, as it's pretty simple, I will only say that it involves `getItemIds()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ValueChange` event, that will tell you when a value in your ***marvelous*** `Container` changes. Unfortunately, that event will only tell you which `Property` was changed and the new value.

As you only have that info, you must loop your container to recalculate things, despite being that a monstrosity in time cost `[O(n*m) being n=nº columns and m=nº rows]`.

To loop your container, you can use this simple code (it's the simplest way to do it, without any complicated logic and stuff):

```
container.addValueChangeListener(ev -> {
    List<?> itemIds = container.getItemIds();
    for(Object itemId: itemIds) {
        Item item = container.getItem(itemId);
        Integer firstNumber = (Integer) item.getItemProperty("firstNumber").getValue();
        Integer secondNumber = (Integer) item.getItemProperty("secondNumber").getValue();
        item.getItemProperty("result").setValue(firstNumber+secondNumber);
    }
});
```